# Error in installing wince application via activesync on vista sp2

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-vista, windows-ce, installation

I have created an installer for my wince application by following the instructions on this site http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446504.aspx. And it worked fine on windows xp. But when I tried to install this using windows vista sp2, there is an error that says "Error 1001. An exception occured in the OnBeforeInstall event handler of InstallerDLLCustomInstaller. --> Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
I don't know what I am missing here. It looks perfect on windows xp. Has anybody encountered this problem? Please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured already :(=). I need to download windows mobile device center for windows vista. Because the existing mobile device center doesn't have ceappmgr.exe that is responsible for installing applications for wince.